# Is there StockTwits history?

Tags: stocktwits

I would like to build an NLP predictive model based on stock tweets via StockTwits.com.  I need a lot of history.  Is this available from stocktwits or anywhere else?

I'm sorry for asking this on stack overflow, StockTwits actually directs all discussions here.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking into the API. Here is a entry point link: 
https://api.stocktwits.com/developers/docs/api

You can stream conversations through this interface - 
https://api.stocktwits.com/developers/docs/api#streams-conversation-docs

This interface looks pretty cool for tracking trending messages - 
https://api.stocktwits.com/developers/docs/api#streams-trending-docs